# Recovering a CVS repository from ",v" files

Tags: version-control, cvs, tortoisecvs

I was sent a zip file that contains source code from a CVS repository. All of the source code files are ",v" file extension files.  After some research, I read that I needed to install a CVS client and check out the files.  I installed TortoiseCVS.  However, I cannot check out the files because of an error, "Unknown flag FULL".

I have the CVSROOT set to the top level of my source repository that I was sent. I then use CVS checkout in TortoiseCVS to check out the files in another directory. The fetch list works but I cannot get the files to check out.  The first directory is created fine but when it gets to the first file, that's when I get the error.

I've included screenshots of my work for clarity.

[image: cvs repository files]
[image: snapshot of ,v files]
[image: cvsroot environment variable]
[image: tortoiseCVS checkout module]
[image: error description]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about tortoiseCVS but if you want to recover, I can tell you how to do it on any debian based linux (I think about your problem comes with CVSROOT, so we have to re-init your CVS repository) :

First, install CVS on your ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install cvs
```

then create a directory to unzip your files:

```
mkdir yourRepoName
```

Then untar the files on this repo:

```
cd yourRepoName
unzip -a /path/to/your/file.zip
```

then delete the CVSROOT directory of the unziped repository.

```
rm -rf /path/to/yourRepoName/CVSROOT
```

finally, init your CVS repository another time:

```
cvs -d /path/to/yourRepoName init
```

then you can simply checkout the files without a problem with:

```
cvs -d /path/to/yourRepoName/ checkout fileOrDirectoryToCheckout nameYouWantForFile
```

Remember that do this checkout out of your repository!

Hope it helps, and sorry if my level of english is not good enough.